# .htaccess Doesn't work good (404 page)

Tags: .htaccess

I make .htaccess file for my website to send the visitor to the error page If he make an undefined url

The problem is if make the website like this xxxx.com/index.php/something

That doesn't send me to the error page but it's show the index page without images

.htaccess file

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/error
```

Comment: The question is very unclear - you seem to be mixing at least 3 things here. What exactly is the problem, can you clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known behaviour of Apache. It's got nothing to do with the error document.

Generally, you may be able to reject anything after `/index.php` by setting the [`AcceptPathInfo` parameter](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) in your .htaccess:

```
AcceptPathInfo off
```

But that would probably defeat your purpose, as your index.php file couldn't accept any paths any more and it sounds like that's something it should do.

Likely the best solution for you is to use absolute paths in your images and CSS:

```
<img src="/images/myimage.gif">
```

If `xxxx.com/index.php/something` is an invalid URL, that is something you need to handle *inside your PHP application*. `ErrorDocument` won't help you here because it can't know what is an invalid URL for index.php and what isn't.

Comment: That mean someone want to hack my site or what ? I can give anything you need to help me. I Eased to make my website here I think is Forbidden

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about re hacking - I don't think that is a factor here. The best way to help us help you is to edit your question and make clearer which of the 3 things is the main problem

Comment: I have a website, I make .htaccess file to send the visitor if he makes an undefined url, All things is right here but the small problem is when he makes something after the home page (index) but I make in images src this '/' and it's work without any problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set Apache's [`AcceptPathInfo`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) directive to `Off`.

Comment: I make my website in an online server :'(

Comment: @Y.Saad I'm not sure I understand. Your server is down?

Comment: No, I don't work in a localhost, so, where I make this `AcceptPathInfo` ?

Comment: Either in your `.htaccess` file or in your Apache configuration file.